# Simple htaccess redirects for a vhost with many domains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am working on a site that has about 5 or 6 domains, all pointing to the same host and all displaying the same site. I understand what I should really do is make each of the domains redirect to one but the client doesn't want that.

I need to redirect:

```
xyz.com/abc -> xyz.com/def
aaa.com/abc -> aaa.com/def
bbb.com/abc -> bbb.com/def
```

where the common factor is mapping abc to def.

Currently I'm using

```
Redirect /abc http://xyz.com/def
```

But that obviously redirects from any domain to xyz.com which is not what I want. What's the most simple/reliable way of doing these redirects without losing the current domain?

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(xyz|aaa|bbb)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ http://xyz.com/def [L,R=302,NC]
```

After you're satisfied that rules are working fine then change `302` to `301` to mark it as `"permanent redirect"`.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased the question wrong.. I wanted aaa.com to stay the same etc (also, I didn't want to be explicit about what the domain was).. but I think what you've said here is the right way to go about things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Redirect /abc /def
```

That preserves the host that the request was made for.

Comment: I seem to recall the entire URL is mandatory as the second argument to Redirect..maybe I'm wrong?!

Comment: @JohnHunt it is not required, without the host, it uses the host that the request was made for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to use normal rewrite rules like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^science.*$ /applications/ [R=301,L]

= science/whatever -> /applications/
```